# Flutter and Sembast - Method returns null

Tags: flutter, dart

I try to combine flutter with the sembast nosql database. I created a method to get all db documents and edit the given data.

My method looks like this:

```
Future<List<Minute>> getAll() async {
    final finder = Finder(sortOrders: [SortOrder('timestamp')]);
    final recordSnapshots = await store.find(await _db, finder: finder);

    return recordSnapshots.map((snapshot) {
      final minute = Minute.fromMap(snapshot.value);

      minute.id = snapshot.key;
      return minute;
    }).toList();
  }

get getSum {
    getAll().then((value) {
      int total = value.fold(
          0, (previousValue, element) => previousValue + element.value);
      print(total); // The correct value
      return total; // Here I dont retrieve the value
    });
  }
```

`print(total)` shows me the right value, but in the Widget I don´t retrieve it. I retrieve just `null`. Whats the issue here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use pedantic/strong mode as it should show lint warnings (missing return type and missing return value) that could help solving your issue without running it.

Unoptimized solution based on your code:

```dart
Future<int> getSum() async {
  var minutes = await getAll();
  var total = minutes.fold<int>(
      0, (previousValue, element) => previousValue + element.value);
  return total;
}
```

Possible optimizations:

- avoid the sort order when computing the sum
- only read the value field instead of converting the whole object

Example:

```dart
Future<int> getSum() async {
  var total = 0;
  (await store.find(await _db)).forEach((snapshot) {
    total += snapshot['value'] as int;
  });
  return total;
}
```

Unfortunately the return value cannot be a `String`, it could be a `Future<String>` though (i.e. db calls are async).

as Julian2611 noted you then need to use a [FutureBuilder](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/FutureBuilder-class.html) and for example `.toString()` to convert the value to a string.

Comment: Thanks very much. I understand now what the FutureBuilder does. It works with your example. Only one question: Is there a way to listen for only the value stored in a variable? I am using a Chart as child of my FutureBuilder. I dont need to regenerate the entire Chart with the start animation. I need to listen only to the value passed in a variable. Do you have an idea to achieve this? Thank you! :)

Answer (score 2):

I think you should not return a value inside the `then(...)` maybe return just the future and use a FutureBuilder as widget

Comment: How could I do this? In fact I need a String as return value.

Comment: Yes but you are fetching this in an async operation from the databse  and you are actually returning a Future<List>. So you could just return this Future<List> and pass it to a FutureBuilder which takes care of the async handling and if the data arrives as list you could do some Operations on it and display it within another widget